# Error when determining the sum of entries with an even row and column index in a 2-D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I've initialized an array function:

```
def create_array(k, n, d):
    return np.arange(k).reshape(n, d)
```

Summed even entries:

```
def calc_even_row_col_sum(arr):

    result = 0
    for i in arr:
        if not i % 2:
            result += i
    return result
```

Answer check:

```
stu_ans = calc_even_row_col_sum(create_array(k, n, d))
assert isinstance(stu_ans, np.number)
```

I receive the error:

"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: Can you create  a minimal array  and show the expected  output ? *sum even indices* doesn't make too much sense  to me.

Comment: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]])
It should return 6, because 6 = 0 + 2 + 4.

Comment: That's not a sum of  indices. It's  a sum of values at even row and column index ?

Comment: Can you create a 4 x  4  array as an example for clarity ?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the incorrect wording

Comment: IIUC, you just need `arr[::2, ::2].sum()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, when you use `for i in arr`, `i` represents a row of `arr` and not the index. Thus, doing `if not i%2` is trying to apply the modulus operator to an entire row, prompting your error.

Try it like this instead:

```
def calc_even_row_col_sum(arr):
    result = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(arr):
        if i%2==0:
            result += row[::2].sum()
    return result

>>> calc_even_row_col_sum(np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5))
6
```

Alternative one-liner:

```
def calc_even_row_col_sum(arr):
    return arr[::2,::2].sum()
```